# Having Node module issue after upgrade to native script 8.1.5

Tags: angular, plugins, dependencies, nativescript, node-modules

I have upgraded my Native script Project which was running fine on previous version.
After upgraded to 8.1.5, Having node modules error.

My package.json

```js
{
  "description": "Order Next Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^13.1.1",
    "@nativescript/angular": "^13.0.1",
    "@nativescript/core": "^8.1.5",
    "@nativescript/firebase": "^11.1.3",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^13.1.2",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-checkbox": "^2.0.4",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.9",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "nativescript-accordion": "^5.0.4",
    "nativescript-drop-down": "^5.0.6",
    "nativescript-feedback": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-geolocation": "^5.1.0",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.5.1",
    "nativescript-phone": "^1.4.0",
    "nativescript-ratings": "^1.0.1",
    "nativescript-ripple": "^4.0.1",
    "nativescript-screen-orientation": "^1.0.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^10.0.2",
    "nativescript-youtubeplayer": "^3.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "~7.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.1.1",
    "@nativescript/android": "8.1.1",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.4.0",
    "@nativescript/types": "^8.1.1",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "^5.0.4",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "main": "./src/main.ts"
}
```

I'm getting following errors form the dependencies,

[Click here to see error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhXVe.png)

```
Kindly help me with the solution.
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention which version of nativescript you upgraded from, but when migrating your nativescript project you have to manually modify your code according to this nativescript [migration guide to NS6](https://v6.docs.nativescript.org/angular/releases/upgrade-instructions), [migration guide to NS7](https://blog.nativescript.org/nativescript-7-announcement/) and [migration guide to NS8](https://blog.nativescript.org/nativescript-8-announcement/#updating-to-nativescript-8).

Make sure to follow all the steps, apply the required changes to your code, including running `ns migrate`.

However, in the example you provided, it looks that you didn't update the imports to match Angular 13 and Nativescript 8. Change your imports to the following and you should be ok:

```
import { View, ObservableArray, CoercibleProperty, EventData, Property } from '@nativescript/core';
import { BaseValueAccessor } from "@nativescript/angular";
```

Comment: why nativescript's docs are so crappy ? if it requires code change - why it's not saying that ? and in my case, i'm migrating from NS7 - NS8 and the amount of errors is huge ... but lets say i want to install new from scratch ? why `tns create` still gives me the old one ?